# How to return the next indexOf after a previous?

Tags: java, string, indexof

For example:

```
str = "(a+b)*(c+d)*(e+f)"
str.indexOf("(") = 0
str.lastIndexOf("(") = 12
```

How to get the index in second bracket? 
(c+d) <- this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
 String word = "(a+b)*(c+d)*(e+f)";
 String c = "(";
  for (int index = word.indexOf(c);index >= 0; index = word.indexOf(c, index + 1)) {
       System.out.println(index);//////here you will get all the index of  "("
    }
```

Comment: @baraky : `index >= 0;` is condition in for loop , so sorry i make rollback to my answer again :(

Comment: Still useful almost 7 years later :).

Answer (score 17):

```
int first  = str.indexOf("(");
int next = str.indexOf("(", first+1);
```

have a look at [API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `charAt()` repeatedly
- Use `indexOf()` repeatedly

Try this simple solution for general purpose:

```
    int index =0;
    int resultIndex=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) =='('){
            index++;
            if (index==2){
            resultIndex =i;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOf%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) from Apache Commons, in this case it would be

```
StringUtils.indexof(str, ")", str.indexOf(")") + 1);
```

The idea is that in the last parameter you can specify the starting position, so you can avoid the first ")".

Answer (score 0):

I think have better method !!!

```
String str = "(a+b)*(c+d)*(e+f)";
str = str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("*")), "");
int idx = str.lastIndexOf("(");
```

and "(c+d)" :

```
   str = str.substring(idx);
```