# String Manipulation, pulling certain values from same line

Tags: java, string, excel, csv

I was wondering if there's a way to do something like this:

An excel sheet / csv file has a **single** cell that includes data that looks like -

`User: Bob - String x = "CN=Administrators,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "CN=Domain Users,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"`

`User: Josh - String y = ["CN=Domain Users,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "CN=Local,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "CN=Temp,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"  "CN=Full Time,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"`

`User: Mary - String z = "CN=Administrators,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "CN=Local,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "CN=Temp,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"`

(there are spaces between the CN's, entitlements. 1 cell contains the name of the users, 1 cell contains the entitlements)

Final print should look like:

`User: Bob Entitlement: Administrator, Domain User
User: Josh Entitlement: Domain User, Local, Temp, Full Time
User: Mary Entitlement: Administrator, Local, Temp`

Administrators and Domain Users are both what I want to pull out of the cell. Now, there are multiple different cells that may contain more than 1-5 different CN's, for example the Users Josh and Mary.

In short, I'm not too sure how to manipulate the java string to pull out only Administrator and Domain (and subsequent entitlements starting with `" "CN=`) that can be looped through to hit each cell. Something that could search the string for any values that start with "CN=" then loop through the string to find parts that start with `" "CN=`.

based on the information in the cell. Please let me know if this requires rewording, as it is hard to portray this in text.

Comment: could you clarify the question more?
what I've understood that you have a list of strings and you need to find the ones that has Administrator OR Domain in Entitlement, right?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? is it the User who has Domain or Administrator, your writing is very ambigious, put a good example instead of all those xxx's

Comment: Seems like you could just check whether the line contains "CN=Administrator", and if so, add "Administrator" to the output line. then if it contains "CN=DomainUsers", add "Domain Users" to the output line (prepended with a comma if this is not the first thing added), etc.

Comment: Would a regex like `"CN=([^",]+)` do it for you? See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS7kG5/1). The "Match Information" section on the right shows the values you want, if I understand you right.

Comment: @AhmedAmr - Administrator and Domain User are just examples of entitlements that follow CN=. I require both to be printed since they are both entitlements. I have added a few more examples that could help clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: @GherbiHicham - I have added a few more examples that hopefully help clarify my question. I want to pull anything that comes after `"CN=` and `" "CN=` since the latter is found throughout the string

Comment: @FredK - unfortunately, I need more than just Administrator and Domain Users. There are other users in the examples I have recently added, that may contain other values ie. Temp and Full Time. I need to be able to pull ALL of those values from he string and display them as shown in the final print

Comment: @mudwomp Huh :D so it looks like your structure looks like <name of user> space - space "<first group>" space "<second group>" ok??
And you want to take name of user, something which starts with CN from first group, something which starts with CN from second group ok?

Comment: @Andreas - As long as it prints out the values I am looking for. I have added a few more examples to help clarify what I require.

Comment: @mudwomp Yup, regex will do that. Now you just need to write the code using that regex. Hint: Class is named [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Teaching you regex is off-topic for this site, but there are loads of good articles on the web for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is indexOf function:

```
String str = "Here there everywhere";

int a = str.indexOf("there");  // a is 5
int b = str.indexOf("er");     // b is 1
int c = str.indexOf("eR");     // c is -1, "eR" is not found
```

more examples here: http://codingbat.com/doc/java-string-indexof-parsing.html

If you don't have informations about user on one line you have to prepare it first. Since you have it get it in one string and you can search in it by this method. You need get start and end index.
Than you just use str.substring to prepare strings from which you will make your printout.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

How to get next index of is here: [How to return the next indexOf after a previous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190734/how-to-return-the-next-indexof-after-a-previous)

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple ways to approach that.

But the most naive one is to loop one time through the input and extract what is after CN= till the ',' or '\"' .

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user1 = "User: Bob - String x = \"CN=Administrators,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,CN=AHmed\" \"CN=Domain Users,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\"";
        String user2 = "User: Josh - String y = [\"CN=Domain Users,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\" \"CN=Local,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\" \"CN=Temp,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\"  \"CN=Full Time,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\"";
        String user3 = "User: Mary - String z = \"CN=Administrators,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\" \"CN=Local,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\" \"CN=Temp,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx\"";
        System.out.println(user1.split("-")[0]+"Entitlement "+getCNs(user1));
        //Outputs User: Bob Entitlement [Administrators, xxx, AHmed, Domain Users]
        System.out.println(user2.split("-")[0]+"Entitlement "+getCNs(user2));
        //Outputs User: Josh Entitlement [Domain Users, xxx, Local, Temp, xxx, Full Time, xxx]
        System.out.println(user3.split("-")[0]+"Entitlement "+getCNs(user3));
        //Outputs User: Mary Entitlement [Administrators, xxx, Local, Temp]
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getCNs(String s) {
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 2; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            if(arr[i]=='=' && arr[i-1]=='N' && arr[i-2]=='C'){
                //we found CN=
                i++;
                while(i<s.length()){
                    temp+=arr[i];
                    i++;
                    if(arr[i]==',' ||arr[i]=='\"' ){
                        list.add(temp);
                        temp = "";
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```